# What is the proper way to name a version of a project?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, metadata

I'm working on a project and I'd like to name each version. Something like:

- 1.0 (First)
- 2.0 (Charm)
- 3.0 (Lucky)

And so on. I've created `version.py` with the following content:

```
__version__ = '1.0'
```

Is it okay to have a second line with `__version_name__ = 'First'`? Is there a better way to implement that?

Comment: Use dict or list ??? __version__ = {'1.0' : 'first'}  or __version__ = ['1.0', 'first']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use [Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), e.g. `1.2.3`

1. Major (interface breaking changes)
2. Minor (new features, same interface)
3. Patch (bug and security fixes)

2) Include the name in `__version_info__`, e.g. `__version_info = (1, 2, 3, 'First')`

Comment: isn't `__version_info__` used to indicate **releaselevel** such as *alpha*, *beta*, *candidate* and *final*? e.g. `(1, 2, 3, 'final')`

Comment: Yes. In this case, his name *is* the release level, e.g. Ubuntu follows a similar code name style. Ubuntu 16.04 --> LTS, Xenial Xerus. Given the lack of an 'official' solution, of the places to put a name, `__version_info__` seems the most appropriate IMHO.